Flutter build error: invalid source release: 17
I am using hmssdk_flutter: ^1.10.6 to build live streaming app but while debugging I am getting
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
What went wrong: 
Execution failed for task ':hmssdk_flutter:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. 
error: invalid source release: 17.

Below I have given java version
java version "1.8.0_341"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.341-b10, mixed mode)

Flutter Version
flutter --version
Flutter 3.22.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 761747bfc5 (4 months ago) • 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
Engine • revision edd8546116
Tools • Dart 3.4.3 • DevTools 2.34.3

Android Project Configuration (android/app/build.gradle):
android {
namespace = "com.example.demo2_hms_flutter_application"
compileSdk = 34
ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.demo2_hms_flutter_application"
    minSdk = 21
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName = flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
    }
}

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank
you in advance for your insights!

Error error: invalid source release: 17 tells that your current JDK is unable to build project with sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17 which is used in hmssdk_flutter here.
Actually, I think you have 2 options here:

Update your setup to use JDK at least 17. There are plenty options to do this, such as updating your Android Studio (because newer version will use 17 or even 21) or just updating your JAVA_HOME to point to newer installation. But anyway, use at least JDK 17 if you chose this option

Fork hmssdk_flutter and patch it in a way that it will use     sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 and targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 here. Here is the instructions on how to used forked version.


I do believe that everyone should stick to first option from this answer, because JDK 8 is relatively old and deprecated, and you will have to update sometime soon anyway.

Hi sameri11 thanks for your response. I have updated JAVA_HOME to 21. But still I am getting same issue. can you please provide  more guidance on this.
